# Rails 6.1 | Is there a way to check which associations have already been joined to a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a little framework for dynamically constructing queries in rails (v6.1.7.3) based upon a json request from the front-end. As the use-cases keep growing, one thing that has been a bit of a pain to manage generically is having a way to keep track of which associations have already been joined to a given query scope as well as the alias used for those associations (if applicable)

Is there a built-in mechanism that I can use to determine if a given association has already been joined? And is there a means of determining an association's alias?

Thanks!

```
scope = MyModel.where(...)
...
scope.joins!(:assoc)
...
# how to determine if :assoc has already been joined to scope?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails [do it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L494-L497) work for you, you don't need to check if some association is already used:

```rb
self.joins_values |= args
```

Here [`Array#|`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Array.html#method-i-7C) method is used. It returns the union of arrays, duplicates are removed:

```rb
ary = [1]
ary |= [1, 2]
ary |= [2, 3]
ary # => [1, 2, 3]
```

But you can check it with `joins_values` or / and `left_outer_joins_value` method. These methods return array of associations (symbol array) and work such way:

```rb
MyModel.joins(:assoc).where(condition).joins_values
# => [:assoc]

MyModel.where(condition).joins_values
# => []

MyModel.left_joins(:assoc).where(condition).left_outer_joins_values
# => [:assoc]

MyModel.where(condition).left_outer_joins_values
# => []
```

There are also `includes_values`, `eager_load_values`, `preload_values` methods:

```rb
MyModel.includes(:assoc).where(condition).includes_values
# => [:assoc]

MyModel.where(condition).includes_values
# => []

MyModel.eager_load(:assoc).where(condition).eager_load_values
# => [:assoc]

MyModel.where(condition).eager_load_values
# => []

MyModel.preload(:assoc).where(condition).preload_values
# => [:assoc]

MyModel.where(condition).preload_values
# => []
```

Comment: Just what I needed - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "method_defined?" to check if exists the associations.

1. Check if User has_one Address Association: User.method_defined?(:address)
2. Check if User has_many Addresses Association: User.method_defined?(:addresses)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Question is not about defining association in the model. And basically associations add instance, not class methods. To check if association is defined it's better to use reflections